# Best way to add a code generation step in the build process?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a python script that modifies a part of a java class (add static fields) according to another file.

What is the best way to add it in the Gradle build process (My script requires pyton3 (so it would be better to tell the user if he doesn't have it) and need to be executed before the java compilation) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what the *best* way to run python from gradle is, but one candidate is to use the exec task:

```
task runPython(type:Exec) {
   workingDir 'path_to_script'
   commandLine /*'cmd', '/c'*/ 'python', 'my_script.py'
}
```

You might have to add `cmd` and `/c` on windows. You can also parse/assert on stdout for success conditions. See here for [more about Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).

As for ensuring that this task always runs before compileJava, you have to add this task as a `dependsOn` for the compileJava task:

```
compileJava.dependsOn runPython
```

alternate syntax:

```
compileJava{
    dependsOn runPython
}
```

When compileJava dependsOn runPython, runPython is executed first everytime compileJava is invoked.

Comment: Is there a way to make it multiplatform, and also to add a kind of variable the user can change in a configuration (something like CMAKE) ?

Comment: I've had the exec command work for me on windows without using the cmd and /c params. Not sure if that only works for certain gradle versions, because the documentation certainly does not reflect it. There are also 3rd party plugins for platform independence: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.jlouns.cpe